# Allow comment highlighting inside biblatex entries

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex

The default syntax highlighting for `bib` files doesn't highlight comments inside entries, like this:

```
@book{test,
    % title = {This isn't highlighted as a comment},
}
```

That's because `bibtex` doesn't allow comments inside entries, but `biblatex` does and I never use `bibtex`, so I want to add the highlighting myself.

I tried adding this to `~/.vim/after/syntax/bib.vim`:

```
syn match testComment "%.*$"
highlight link testComment Comment
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas on how I can make stuff after a `%` count as a comment anywhere on the file?

PS: Ideally the `%` still wouldn't count as a comment if it's inside a field, like `url = {http://whatever.com%20whatever}`… but I think I can figure out a regex pattern to account for that if I can get the highlighting to work inside entries at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that the match is inside an `bibEntry`. Thus you have to redefine the `bibEntry` region so as to include (with the `contains=` option a comment group. In this case, you should use a new comment group, not the existing `bibComment` and `bibComment2`, because these are reserved for standard bibtex comments.

I think the following should work if you put it in `.../after/syntax/bib.vim`:

```
syn region bibEntryData contained
  \ start=/[{(]/ms=e+1
  \ end=/[})]/me=e-1
  \ contains=bibKey,bibField,bibComment3
syn match bibComment3 "^\s*%.*"
highlight link bibComment3 Comment
```

Note: This assumes that all comments are "full line"-comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That works for a few random comments, but not for most. It doesn't work with my example, for instance (`% title = {This isn't…`).

Comment: Ah, I think the updated answer works. We needed to go one level deeper into the nested syntax definitions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I don't know much about how the `contains=` thing works, but I just replaced the regex pattern with `"%.*"` and it seems to work perfectly even for end-of-line comments. I worried that would cause problems with `url` fields like I mentioned in the "PS", but the comments still aren't highlighted inside each field's brackets, so it works great!